# notas arduino,Buzzer

Tags: arduino

hola bueno no llego a comprender del todo como funcionan las notas el el Arduino de todo, miren les explico cuando hay que tocar una melodía mas o menos larga se hace esto en código:

```
#define NOTE_C1  33
#define NOTE_CS1 35
#define NOTE_D1  37
#define NOTE_DS1 39
#define NOTE_E1  41
#define NOTE_F1  44
#define NOTE_FS1 46.
```

lo que yo no comprendo es por que se utilizan esto para generar las notas desde ya gracias de ante mano(cabe aclarar que ya e trabajado con buzzers pero accionado con motores nada de manera automatica)

Answer (score 1):

aquí se está definiendo únicamente la frecuencia redondeada en Herzios, de cada nota en la octava 1. Es el equivalente a:

- Do / C    1oct. 32,70Hz
- Do# / C#  1oct. 334,65Hz
- Re / D    1oct. 336,71Hz
- Re# / D#  1oct. 338,89Hz
- Mi / E    1oct. 341,20Hz
- Fa / F    1oct. 343,65Hz
- Fa# / F#  1oct. 346,25Hz

Es por ese motivo que en tu lista de variables, defines el Do de la octava 1 como `NOTE_C1  33` con la frecuencia redondeada a 33Hz

NOTA: Se utiliza `#define NOTE_CS1 35` en lugar de `int NOTE_CS1 = 35;` porque se trata de un valor constante, que no variará.

Luego para que suene por el pin 3 (qué es PWM) en tu buzzer, el código (con un ejemplo de notas y tiempos) sería:

```
void setup()
{
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);      // Fija el pin 3 como salida.

// Define frecuencia de las notas 
#define NOTE_C1  33
#define NOTE_CS1 35
#define NOTE_D1  37
#define NOTE_DS1 39
#define NOTE_E1  41
#define NOTE_F1  44
#define NOTE_FS1 46

//Define tiempos en milisegundos
#define Corchea 500
#define Semicorchea 250
#define Fusa    125

}

void loop()
{
tone(3, NOTE_C1, Semicorchea);      // Lanza señal Do de la octava 1 a 33Hz por el pin 3 durante 250ms (equivalente a una Semicorchea).
}
```

Es importante que el pin por el que se lanza sea PWM para poder variar el tiempo.

Comment: Oki lo entiendo y muchas gracias pero otra duda no sirve de igual manera define que const int desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Por supuesto que sirve, teniendo en cuenta las diferencias. Echa un vistazo https://parzibyte.me/blog/2017/12/08/diferencia-define-const-arduino/

Comment: Muchas gracias :)